# VBA Function to split comma delimited cell

Tags: vba, excel

I need to split some data in a Cell that is separated by comma. I know this can be down the the text to column excel function but I need it to be in VBA because this process has to be automatic. I created this function:

```
Function SepararDatos(splitVal As Variant)
Dim totalVals As Long

splitVal = Split(splitVal, ",")
totalVals = UBound(splitVal)
Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1 + totalVals)).Value = splitVal
End Function
```

but I don't know why it isn't working. If I change it to a `sub` it works great but it's not what i need. Can someone tell me how to change the function to work. Also the sub returns string but i would like to return number.

Comment: So you want to enter this into a cell as a formula and have it work?

Comment: Yes is that possible?

Comment: Yes and no, see my answer for three ways to do what you want, the third does not use vba but native formulas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A UDF used as a formula cannot affect the value of another cell.  So you have two methods you can use:

Array enter:

```
Function SepararDatos(splitval As String)
Dim splitval2() As String

splitval2 = Split(splitval, ",")

SepararDatos = splitval2
End Function
```

Then highlight enough output cells. with the first being active:

[image]

Then in the formula bar type:

```
=--SepararDatos(A1)
```

And instead of Enter hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter to array enter the formula.  Excel will put the formula in all three cells with `{}` around them.  These will be linked in an array.

The `--` turns it into numbers that you can then format in your desired manner

[image]

---

Second method, need a second criterion:

```
Function SepararDatos(splitval As String, i As Long)
Dim splitval2() As String

splitval2 = Split(splitval, ",")

SepararDatos = splitval2(i - 1)
End Function
```

Then in the first cell you enter:

```
=--SepararDatos($A$1,COLUMN(A:A))
```

And drag across.  The `--` turns the string into numbers.

[image]

---

A third method is to use native formula:

```
=--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A$1,",",REPT(" ",999)),(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*999+1,999))
```

And drag across:

[image]

Comment: All of them works perfect thanks a lot. Just 1 question how do i efficiently add a `IFERROR` in the second or third method. I tried putting it first but it doesn't work.